# Create subfolders based on part of filename

Tags: python

I am trying to create sub-folders based on parts of the filenames. I have the following examples of files in the directory:

```
xxx.01.741425.xlsx
xxx.12.658521.xlsx
xxx.01.667423.xlsx
xxx.12.125867.xls
xxx.12.355456.xlsx
```

I want all the files with `01` after `xxx.` in one subfolder named `01`, all the files with `12` after `xxx.` in another subfolder named `12`, and so on. I am trying to do it with the following code with no success.

```
import os
import shutil
import sys
dr = sys.argv[1]; files = os.listdir("C:\Folder")
for f in [f for f in files if os.path.isfile ("C:\Folder"+"/"+f)]:
    folder = "C:\Folder"+"/"+f.split(".")[1]
    if not os.path.exists(folder):
        os.makedirs(folder)
    shutil.move("C:\Folder"+"/"+f, folder+"/"+f)
```

Comment: with no success? means? be careful of windows paths without the raw prefix BTW.

Comment: Edit your question to include the full error message. Also, try printing `folder`, does it look correct? And lookup `os.path.join()` in the Python docs.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I just needed to modify 
folder = "C:\Folder"+"/"+f.split(".")[1]
to folder = "C:\Folder"+"/"+f.split(".")[1].replace(f.split(".")[2]